# Simplification of complex rational?

Tags: complex-numbers, rational-numbers, partial-fractions, fractional-part, rationalising-denominator

I was looking at a problem in a textbook and found the following simplification:

$$\frac{1}{x+i\omega} * \frac{2y}{y^2 + \omega^2} = \frac{2}{xy} * \frac{1}{1+i\frac{\omega}{x}}*\frac{1}{1 + (\frac{\omega}{y})^2}$$

and I have no clue how they did this simplification? Is this like some well known formula? I tried multiplying by the complex conjugate but that doesn't seem to help so any guidance/formulas they used would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $y^2$, and $x+i\omega=x\left(1+i\frac\omega x\right)$

Comment: got it thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide top and bottom by $y^2$, and $x+i\omega=x\left(1+i\frac\omega x\right)$